# how to convert a randomly generated graph to csv file?

Tags: python, networkx

I have generated a random graph, how can I save it to a csv file?

```
g=networkx.erdos_renyi_graph(100,.3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you store networkx graphs as edge-list - there is a dedicated method to do that (and read it back in as well):

```
import networkx as nx

g=nx.erdos_renyi_graph(100,.3)
nx.write_edgelist(g, "file.csv")
```

See

- [networkx: write_edgelist](https://networkx.org/documentation/networkx-1.7/reference/generated/networkx.readwrite.edgelist.write_edgelist.html)
- [networkx: read_edgelist](https://networkx.org/documentation/networkx-1.7/reference/generated/networkx.readwrite.edgelist.read_edgelist.html)

If you really need a csv, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23768079/networkx-writing-results-to-csv-for-multiple-measures) might help.